# How to install python with git bash and npm in windows

Tags: python, node.js, windows, bash, npm

currently using windows 7 machine to check cross browser testing. When doing `npm install`, it says `node-gyp rebuild`, then it looks for python executable.

I am using git bash and set

- `PATH=$PATH:/c/my_account/.../anaconda3/python.exe`
- `PYTHON=$PATH:/c/my_account/../anaconda3/python.exe`
- `PYTHONPATH=$PATH:/c/my_account/../anaconda3/python.exe in .bashrc`

With this setup, I still have same error.

What is the proper way to install python in windows machine, so git bash and `npm` is aware of it?

It is a corporate machine, so technique like `npm install -g windows-build-tools` won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

*PATH variables are for listing paths (i.e. directories or folders). As such, you should remove "python.exe" from the end of each of these lines.

The PATH variable should be a colon-separated list of any directories that contain executables you would like to run without having to specify a relative or absolute path. To the best of my knowledge, PYTHON is not used by anything and perhaps need not be defined. You (very probably) do *NOT* want to include $PATH when defining PYTHONPATH. It should be just the location of your Python installation.

If you put these in `.bashrc`, you also want to `export` them so they are defined in your environment after `.bashrc` finishes execution.

```
export PATH=/c/my_account/.../anaconda3:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/c/my_account/.../anaconda3
```

As a side note, you might try running `which python` or `which python.exe`. If that command points to the correct version of Python, your path variables are probably set up correctly.

Comment: Tried it. Error is cannot find python executable C:\users\my_account\.....\python.exe, you can set the PYTHON env variable.